# Matching with "if" in flex lexical analyzer

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am trying to write a piece of code in flex that matches the "if" keyword. When I write:

```
if printf("Saw an if");
```

it matches but it also matches, for example if the input is **abcdifcd**, output becomes **abcdSaw an ifcd**, but I want to be invalid, i.e. the output must be **abcifcd** since it is invalid. In other words, I want it to be valid only if the keyword "if" is found alone, for example I want **if abcd** or **abcd if** to be valid but **ifa, aif** etc. to be invalid. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a rule which matches "words", whatever you consider them to be. Remember to put the rule for "if" first. For example:

```
"if"         printf("Saw a if");
[a-zA-Z]+    ECHO
```